# Adding to a saved Python file?

Tags: python

I recently (as in yesterday) started learning how to program in Python 3. This is my first time programming. I was following along with a video tutorial on YouTube and saved the file of notes when I was finished. I opened it again today and tried to add more to it, but I wasn't able to; the ">>>" separating each input line was no longer there. Is there a way to keep adding to a previously saved file, or do I just have to copy that file into a new one and continue appending things from there? I'm using a Windows OS if that's at all relevant. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using python IDLE for coding or something else?

Comment: @MuthuKumar I'm using the IDLE

Comment: IDLE is like a compiler it doesn't save your file. In IDLE choose `ctrl+N` a new python file created Use that file to code and save and run It will be saved in particular location. You can edit whenever you need

Comment: @MuthuKumar Ah, that explains it! Thank you so much for the clarification.

Comment: When it’s prepended with “>>>”, it indicates that you’re using the interactive console, and that everything resets when a new console is opened. If you want your script to save, you will need to write to a file. Ie. press `ctrl+N`(windows) `Command+N`(OSX). Or create a `.py` file and open with Idle